# Can a transmuter wizard own multiple transmuter's stones, i.e. keeping the ones produced by his simulacra?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, dnd-adventurers-league

Are there proscriptions in AL to prevent a transmuter wizard from owning multiple transmuter's stones?  The idea is to keep the ones producted by his simulacra and keeping them also in different modules.  Is this allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read through the Adventurers League Players Guide v9.1 and the Adventurers League FAQ v9.0, and I could not find a rule preventing this.

It appears that you could get arbitrarily many transmuter's stones in this way.  Initially you would be limited by the material component cost of 1500gp per *simulacrum* spell, but once your simulacra get *wish* you can remove that limitation.  These related questions have more details:

[Can the simulacrum of a transmuter create its own transmuter's stone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107586/can-the-simulacrum-of-a-transmuter-create-its-own-transmuters-stone?rq=1)  (answer is yes)

[What happens to a wizard's transmuter's stone when she dies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104655/what-happens-to-a-wizards-transmuter-stone-when-she-dies?rq=1) (answer is it still exists)

Adventurers League has rules about trading magic items, but the transmuter's stone does not appear to be a magic item per that definition.  (If it were a magic item, transmuter wizards would have to count it as part of their own magic item limit, which seems unfair.)

Adventurers League also has rules about simulacrums (preventing you from exploits involving *wish* or chained *simulacrum*) but this specific exploit is not prohibited.

However, please note that the Adventurers League DM has Rule 0 authority over what happens at their table.  It's likely that many Adventurers League DMs would consider your plan to be an abuse and would tell you that it's forbidden at their table, even though there's no official rule against it.

Comment: Note that the material cost of *simulacrum* can be bypassed once *wish* is an option, making this a lot more practical.

Comment: One thing to note is that only one stone would actually belong to the wizard. Once the simulacra are gone, there would be no way to change the "mode" of the other stones, nor would there be a way to use the Master Transmuter feature with them. Both of these features only work for the stone that specifically belongs to the wizard.

Comment: [p. 11 of the FAQ](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv9.pdf#page=11) does mention: "***You Are You; and So Is It.*** If a *simulacrum* you have created casts *wish*, both you and your *simulacrum* suffer the stress associated with casting the spell—including the risk of being forever unable to cast *wish* again. The inability to cast *wish* extends to any *simulacrum* you create in the future, as well as *wish* cast by deities via Divine Intervention or other, similar class features." There's no mention of whether this extends to things besides *wish*, though...